# How to enable Speaking Mode in JDA Bot (Java Discord API)

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I developing a Discord bot on Java, using JDA v5.0.0-alpha.1. My current target is forcing bot to use voice mode in channel to broadcast audioStream of one of my audio device. For that I use function that set AudioSendHandler to bot AudioManager and open connection of user's voice channel:

```
public void startStream(SlashCommandEvent event) {
        AudioManager manager = Objects.requireNonNull(event.getGuild()).getAudioManager();
        AudioFormatter stream = new AudioFormatter();
        manager.setSendingHandler(stream);
        manager.setSpeakingMode(SpeakingMode.VOICE);
        if (event.getMember().getVoiceState().inAudioChannel()) {
            manager.openAudioConnection(event.getMember().getVoiceState().getChannel());
        }
        while (true) {
        }
        //manager.closeAudioConnection();
    }
```

But after writting a command, bot connect to user's channel and stay silent. How can I force him to use a Speaking Mode?
Code of my AudioSendHandler class:

```
public class AudioFormatter implements AudioSendHandler {
    AudioFormat format;
    TargetDataLine targetDataLine;
    byte[] buffer;
    ByteBuffer returnedAudio;

    public AudioFormatter() {
        this.format = new AudioFormat((float)48000, 16, 2, true, true);
        this.targetDataLine =  AudioDevice.getAudioDevice();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canProvide() {
        buffer = new byte[48000 * 2 * 2 / 50];
        int bytesRead = targetDataLine.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        returnedAudio = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer);
        return true;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public ByteBuffer provide20MsAudio() {
        return returnedAudio;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isOpus() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

On debugging, I notice, that object of AudioSendHandler class was created but method canProvide() was never invoked.

Comment: Speaking modes are unrelated to whether the bot is muted. You should consider removing the while(true) loop, since it will just stop your bot from working.

Comment: Sorry, I say wrong, bot stay silent, doesn't muted. But if I remove while(true) loop, bot starts recursive reconnect to the voice channel. Maybe exist some method that should starting calling canProvide() method? Unfortunately I can't find anything on documentation

Comment: try updating jda, and in the future you should make sure to properly describe your problem in your original post. The loop only makes your bot stop working entirely.